# Best practice to display rating image without using switch statement in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've a table view with a number of places whose rating is calculated using cloud code in parse. I currently use switch statement to display the images according to the obtained rating. Here's my current code.

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"calculateRating"
                   withParameters:@{@"place":cell.placeName.text}
                            block:^(NSNumber *ratings, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@ has %d starts",cell.placeName.text,[ratings intValue]);
                                    rating = [ratings intValue];
                                    switch(rating) {
                                        case 1:
                                            cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1Stars.png"];
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2Stars.png"];
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3Stars.png"];
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"4Stars.png"];
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"5Stars.png"];
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }

                                }

                        }];
```

I tried the following code to solve the issue but it is not working.

```
NSString *ratingImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dStars.png",(int) ratings];
                                    cell.ratingImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:ratingImageName];
```

I get the following error.
-[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108572ce0

Can anyone help me the best way to display the 5 rating images I have according to the retrieved rating?

Comment: I'll wager any amount that `ratings` is `NSNull` since you didn't type check it upon receipt, and both versions of your code would exhibit the exact same problem. Which selector is unrecognised and which line raises the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see a `switch` like that, think "array".

Make an `NSArray`, pre-populate it with images in such a way that `kStars.png` is at index `k`, and put it in an instance variable:

```
_ratingImages = @[
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"0Stars.png"]
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1Stars.png"]
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"2Stars.png"]
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3Stars.png"]
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"4Stars.png"]
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"5Stars.png"]
];
```

Now you can replace the switch with a single assignment:

```
cell.ratingImage.image=_ratingImages[rating];
```

An important advantage to this approach is that the images are created only once, and cached on the class instance. This saves you from unnecessary lookups and object construction.

**Note:** In case you rather make your code work, the reason it's not working is that you are using a cast instead of calling `intValue`:

```
NSString *ratingImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dStars.png",[ratings intValue]];
```

Comment: I tried this too but the error was the same. That's why I went for a cast. Also I get this error after making the correction.

Comment: Also I get this error after making the correction.                                            -[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104e10ce0. What could be the problem? I get perfect output with switch.

Comment: The issue was related to Parse access. I got the ratings done with a single line of code.                  cell.ratingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dStars.png",rating]];

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code solves the issue in a single line.
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dStars.png",rating]];